# what is equivalent of MySQL of DBMS_OUTPUT

Tags: mysql, oracle, dbms-output

I try to write a MySQL strored procedure, and want to send some output to console, or stdout.
Oracle use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE to debugginf.

Is there an equivalent of DBMS_OUTPUT in MySQL stored procedures?

Answer (score 12):

In Oracle :

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.put('Hello World');
```

In MySQL :

```
SELECT 'Hello World!';
```